# Can I Craft A Wand of Fireball at CL 4?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Do I have to make an item have the minimum possible caster level required to cast it, or can I even go lower than that?  Does a Wizard crafting a wand of fireball have to craft it as a CL 5 item, or can she craft it as a CL 4 or even as a CL 1 as well?

Comment: To clarify, is the problem that your character is below level 5, but has access to *fireball* (somehow) and the Craft Wand feat (even harder to get at that level) and you want to craft a wand?  Or is your character's level irrelevant and you just want to craft it at a lower level than normal?

Comment: I am currently playing as an Artificer in a Eberron conversion game, which means I technically have access to fireball despite have only four levels in the class.  I have access to every spell in the game, really, and I have the ability to craft spell-trigger items via the Craft Wondrous Item feat.  But, since I am getting the spell from the Wizard spell list, I suppose the minimum CL needed to craft this spell-trigger item is CL 5.  What I'm wondering is if there is a way to circumvent this requirement - first by asking if I can just craft this item at a lower CL, thus meaning that 5 really

Comment: isn't the minimum CL, or, alternative, if I could just add 5 to the DC like I have been reading from Paizo forums regarding other item creation  requirements.

Comment: @user3735278 If I'm remembering correctly, the Eberron artificer has a class feature that explicitly states that you can craft magic items at two caster levels below that which the item usually requires as a minimum, and the example it gives is a wand of fireball. You, uh, might want to flip through the  class features again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Since you are required to be a 5th level Wizard to cast a Fireball spell, it must be crafted as a CL5 wand. You can go higher, and make a CL10 Fireball wand, but you cannot go below CL5, as that's the minimum level required to cast the spell.

From the following document: http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html

**Magic Item Creation**

> While item creation costs are handled in detail below, note that normally the two primary factors are the caster level of the creator and the level of the spell or spells put into the item. **A creator can create an item at a lower caster level than her own, but never lower than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell.** Using metamagic feats, a caster can place spells in items at a higher level than normal.

**Craft Wand**

> **The creator must have prepared the spell to be stored (or must know the spell, in the case of a sorcerer or bard) and must provide any focuses the spell requires.** Fifty of each needed material component are required (one for each charge). Material components are consumed when work begins, but focuses are not. A focus used in creating a wand can be reused. **The act of working on the wand triggers the prepared spell, making it unavailable for casting during each day devoted to the wand's creation.** (That is, that spell slot is expended from the caster's currently prepared spells, just as if it had been cast.)

Also, you must be CL5 to take the feat "Craft Wand"

From http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-wand-item-creation---final

> Craft Wand (Item Creation)
>
> You can create magic wands.
>
> Prerequisite: **Caster level 5th.**
>
> Benefit: You can create a wand of any 4th-level or lower spell that you know. Crafting a wand takes 1 day for each 1,000 gp in its base price. To craft a wand, you must use up raw materials costing half of this base price. A newly created wand has 50 charges.

However, if you're looking for a low level damage spell and you want to make a wand at a lower Caster level, you might want to give [Burning hands](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/burninghands.html) or [Scorching Ray](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/scorchingRay.html) a shot.

Comment: Let's say that, hypothetically, I am CL 4 and, yet, I have access to the fireball spell.  Can I add +5 to the Spellcraft DC to make a wand of fireball?  I know that there are a myriad of situations in which you can add 5 to the DC when you don't meet a magic item requirement, and I'm wondering if this may be one of them.

Comment: @user3735278 if you can cast the spell at CL 4, CL 4 ***is*** the "minimum level needed to cast the needed spell", so the first paragraph doesn't concern you, and you can craft the item normally.

Comment: I'm afraid not. In order to gain access to the Craft Wand feat you must have a CL5. It's a prerequisite required to take the feat.

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2k74y?Magic-Item-Creation-and-Caster-Level#4) is a key post in a very long thread about magic item creation (and a developer confirms down the line on page 1 that the contributor is correct, also around page 3 it devolves into childish arguments I don't suggest reading).  Caster Level is not a requirement at all unless it is listed in the Requirements section of an item (and it is not listed there for generic wands).  <s>However, as a wand is a spell-trigger item, you MUST have access to an actual spell of the wand you want to create (*fireball*, in this case), you cannot make up for it.</s> From your class description:  Artificer Knowledge: ... can create spell trigger, spell completion ... items without having the ability to cast the necessary spells ...

By the rules as they stand, **a CL 4 character can make a wand of *fireball* - at ANY CL 5 or higher - as long as they have the Craft Wand feat and can cast *fireball* or can obtain and use scrolls or similar to do so.**

Unfortunately for you, that artificer class doesn't gain Craft Wand as a bonus feat until level 7, and it can't be selected normally until CL 5.  Therefore, **you cannot craft a wand of *fireball* (or any spell at all) until you reach level 5 at minimum**, and I would suggest waiting until you get the feat for free at 7, but that's debatable.  Once you have the feat, though, you can make a wand of *wish* for all the rules care, if you don't mind having to set the CL of the wand at 17.

Note that making a high-CL wand can be very difficult, because the CL sets the DC.  It also significantly increases the price.  Also note that **it remains impossible to create a CL 4 wand of *fireball*.** A CL 4 caster can make a CL 5 wand of *fireball*, but no one can make a CL 4 wand of *fireball*.  I hope I clarified that enough.

Comment: Frst, I would like to thank you for providing this great answer somewhat blindly.  If it would help you refine your answer in any way, here is a link to the class in question: https://sites.google.com/site/eberronpathfinder/conversion-info/classes/artificer.

The ability pretaining to crafting items without knowing the spell is named "Artificer Knowledge".

Comment: @user3735278 Updated the answer with your class info.  It didn't work out in your favor, because you don't have access to Craft Wand at Artificer 4.  Also, thank you very much for that link, because I've been looking for a good Artificer conversion ^_^

Comment: Unless Pathfinder changed the Magic item Creation rules to the point where you can no longer use Craft Wondrous Item to make custom spell-trigger items like you could in 3.5, I think that making a spell-trigger item, like a wand, through that feat is quite possible.

Comment: You must be at Least CL5 to gain access to the Craft Wand Feat. It is a prerequisite.

Comment: @user3735278 With DM approval, you could use Craft Wondrous to make a wand-*like* item that is spell-trigger, has charges, and casts fireball, but it wouldn't be a *wand*. It'd be a custom Wondrous item, and would have whatever construction requirements and other traits the DM assigned to it. As a DM, be cautious about allowing this particular type of custom item, as it tends to lead to rendering item creation feats other than Craft Wondrous irrelevant